# How can we retrieve the epoch number from Keras ModelCheckpoint?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, callback, tensorflow2.0

While training my ML model, I applied CSVlogger and the ModelCheckpoint callbacks so basically all epochs metric results are logged by the CSVlogger and only best model saved.

However with *save_best_only* for ModelCheckpoint, how can we get/log the epoch number when the model is updated by ModelCheckpoint in the last time, just as **an integer number**.

```
csv_logger =CSVlogger('history.csv', append=True, seperator=";")
callbacks = [csv_logger,
             tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
results = model.fit(X,Y, callbacks=callbacks, epochs=30)

# how can we have something like lastSavedEpoch =  results.last_saved_epoch? 
# e.g. it's lastly updated in 27th epoch although total training epochs is 30.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi I also use another by the callback methods , I can easily extract
> information as these below :

```
lossvalue: 1.1057155132293701
accvalue: 0.6833927035331726
val_loss: None
val_acc: None
epoch: 1
step: 64
step: 10009601
best acc: 0.0
```

> Anyway you do it using CSV logger from model fitting, try find where
> is a best accuracy as you finding or not !?

```
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0.5, 1])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```